# Upgrade to 1.92 Category tree showing, bug general information not

Tags: magento-1.9, category, backend

Upgraded to 1.92 and the front end works fine, but the back end there is only the category tree under manage categories. General information blank, as well there are no products linked to the category.

Any help to populate these would be greatly appreciated!

[image]

Answer (score 0):

The trouble appears to be caused when rerouting the primary domain into a subfolder.
Works for: [website/magento/...]
but when you reroute it by changing the .htaccess to [website/...] so it does not show the magento folder, that is where the problem was caused.

I was advised by siteground that this is my issue. Rerouting is definitely a problem for Magento and siteground. So my solutions were:

1. Install magento directly into the primary domain [public_html], which I did not want to do as I have many sites under this.
2. Change my primary domain to something else, and set it up as a subdomain.

Number 2 worked for me. I changed my primary domain to a website that was only doing forwarding, and now my other site, is under it's own folder and I have no websites installed directly onto the public_html folder.